# Create JSON from two arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, json

I have two arrays say: `x=[1,2,3]` and `y=['a', 'b', 'c']`. I want to create a json using x and y arrays in **rails console**. What is the optimized way to do it.
The desired JSON should looks like this:

```
{
    "obj":
        [
            {
                "key":"a",
                "value": 1
            },
            {
                "key":"b",
                "value": 2
            },
            {
                "key":"c",
                "value": 3
            }
        ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Yes, i did using a for loop, I created a string by appending appropriate parts then converted to json. But I believe rails must be offering some better way.

Comment: Rails has nothing to do with this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x = [1,2,3] and y = ['a', 'b', 'c']
{obj: y.zip(x).map { |k, v| {key: k, value: v} } }

#⇒ {
#  :obj => [
#    {
#        :key => "a",
#      :value => 1
#    },
#    {
#        :key => "b",
#      :value => 2
#    },
#    {
#        :key => "c",
#      :value => 3
#    }
#  ]
# }
```

If you insist on having string keys:

```
{ 'obj' => y.zip(x).map { |k, v| { 'key' => k, 'value' => v } } }
```

To get a json out of the hash, just call `to_json` on it.